# HTTP-only cookie update in Next js 13.4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm doing a full-stack application in Nest JS + Next JS.
For JWT authorization I use HTTP-only cookies, when I do log in or register a request in the "use client" components, everything works correctly and HTTP-only cookies are set.

However, when the access token expires, I need to update it by contacting the Nest JS server. I tried to make an Axios interceptor to solve this problem. And if the function that needed the access token (like the get current user function) is called in the SSR component, the interceptor sends a request to the server to get new tokens, then the tokens are not set in the client cookie.

I don't understand how I can set HTTP-only cookies from SSR components. I tried all methods including middleware, interceptor, fetch, and so on, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use express' res.cookie() to set the cookies in your refreshToken endpoint, or create a helper class / function that uses it

Comment: I tried that but when I send a request from a component without using "use client" it doesn't work. When I send requests from the "use client" component I use your solution and it works fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).